# No Refresh button in solution explorer VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am missing refresh button in solution explorer for ASP.Net Core projects However for other project types(Console, WPF...) it appears on solution explorer panel.

devenv /SafeMode   also did not help here.

My environment is VS 2015 Ent update 3 on Win 10

Google has not returned any useful results for this search either.

Any one know fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no refresh button for .NET Core/.xproj related projects (and most likely for .NET Core projects using the new .csproj structure), because the Visual Studio tooling for it constantly monitors the folder and updates it whenever a file is added or removed.

Just add/remove/rename a file in Explorer and it instantly becomes available/visible in Visual Studio. The files are not included anymore in the *.csproj file as it was the case before.

Comment: That's fine, Version control are not picking up those changes in solution explorer(refactoring, rename variable, class name etc..), I have Ankh SVN, which I think expects some event/notification from VS, Which obviously Ankh not receiving in case of Core world.

Comment: The integrated TeamExplorer (Git, TFS, VSTS) works fine with it. You'd have to contact the developers of Ankh SVN to have a look at it or use explorer extensions (i.e. TortoiseSVN) and check in/out outside of VS

Comment: DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3  Installed today and it seems it behaving fine now...